# Memory management when wrapping code from C++ to C#

Tags: c#, c++, memory-management, void-pointers, word-wrap

I am trying to wrap my C++ code into C#.
I managed to export my functions to DLL and then import them from C#.

My problem is as follows:

In my C++ code I have a singleton which i create by using the "createInstance" function. In my new newCreateInstance function which I export to the DLL I just call the old createInstance and then return a void pointer pointing the singletone instance which I have created.

In other function I try to operate on the singletone instance. So, I get a void pointer, which I then cast to the relevant pointer, then try to operate on it.

But i think that when I call the second function (after calling the first) from C# my singletone instance is already been erased from memory. How do i keep the instance on my heap/stack? is it even possible or should i do it differently?

p.s - I can't create same class on C# cause i don't know it's implementation (It also comes from a DLL/LIB file). So i have to use void pointers.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Post some code of what you're talking about, so that we can tell whether it will go out of memory or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your assumptions are correct about premature garbage collection, you need to use `GC.KeepAlive` as [explained on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.keepalive%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1):

[image: msdn]